# Best suitable SQL server for VB 8 Express Edition?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am about to start a project on VB.. For that I am using Visual Basics 2008 Express Edition.. So I just wanted to know which is the best suitable SQL Server for the same.

Comment: The version of Visual Basic associated with the 2008 Express edition is 9, not 8. Version 8 came with 2005.

Comment: I am aware of this sir, but I need a comptable version SQL server.. So

Comment: But your title says 8. It's inconsistent with the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 was released alongside VS 2008, so one of its variants would be recommended. The Express Edition will work well. If you want to use User Instances (such as when the database file is stored in an `App_Data` folder for a website, you *need* to have Express Edition installed. In addition, if you plan to *use* any data related projects in an actual production environment, but don't want to spend, it's the only option that's freely available.

Of course, you might want to consider the age of the product. VS 2008 itself is 2 generations behind (at present, Jan 2013), as is SQL Server 2008. You can easily use later editions of both SQL Server and Visual Studio (in there Express Editions), and I'd usually recommend moving up to the latest that's installable on your machine.

---

If you're wanting to try out *all* of the SQL Server features, a trial installation or Developer Edition would be recommended - but for the latter, you need an MSDN license, and if you're going that far, you should seriously consider moving up from VS Express.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 hands down. It's free and you can use stored procedures, functions and such.